# Page gaps with sticky CSS elements

Tags: html, css, positioning, sticky

Is there a way to prevent content gaps when using sticky positioning? I was using absolute before and it looked just fine.
The gaps are on top and the sides.

```
div.header{
            background-color:#191a1c;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
        }
```

Comment: Can you share a screen shot

Comment: Please share your html code too or live jsfiddle.

Comment: i cant its business stuff in there

Comment: there is like an invisible border of like 4 pixels around my header element which is supposed to fit the edges of the screen

Comment: @T. Tom can you post screenshot

Comment: try *{margin:0; padding:0;}

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Solved: the solution is `position: fixed`; forget sticky.